# XPath. Getting specific siblings

Tags: xpath, siblings

I'm writing a Google app engine project in python. I need to scrap the banks sites, get the exchange rate from them.

the example of html:

```
<tr> 
                            <td width="2"><img src="./images/zero.gif" width="2" height="2" border="0" /></td>
                            <td width="41" class="curvalsh" align="left" valign="middle"><font color="#DC241F">USD</font></td>
                            <td width="41" class="curvalsh" align="right" valign="middle"><b> 15.20 </b></td>
                            <td width="4" align="left" valign="middle"><img src="./images/zero.gif" width="2" height="20" border="0" hspace="1"></td>
                            <td width="41" class="curvalsh" align="right" valign="middle"><b> 16.00 </b></td>
                            <td width="4" align="left" valign="middle"><img src="./images/zero.gif" width="2" height="20" border="0" hspace="1"></td>
                            <td width="41" class="curvalsh" align="right" valign="middle"> - </td>
                            <td width="2" align="left" valign="middle"><img src="./images/zero.gif" width="2" height="20" border="0" hspace="1"></td>
                        </tr>
```

I need to get the next two  tags with text after tag containing "USD" text(tags with 15.20 and 16.00).

What i've already done is:

```
xpath = "//tr/td[text()='USD']/following-sibling::td/text()"
```

But this doesn't return anything and this is not exactly what i need, because i have to specify to get 2 tags **containing text** after tag "USD", because there are also tags which don't contain any text.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried like this, still returns nothing

```
xpath = "//tr/td[text()='USD']/following-sibling::td[matches(text(),'(^|\W)[0-9]+.[0-9]+($|\W)','i')]/text()"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice that there is another tag inside `td` before getting to the searched text, so you can either search directly:

```
//tr/td/font[text()='USD']......
```

or

```
//tr//font[text()="USD"]......
```

in any case you will then go one level up using `..` much like when browsing the file system.

well, and there is another tag hiding there that you can refer directly using `b/text()` or take all text under next sibling by `//text()`

this is how it might looks:

```
//tr/td/font[text()='USD']/../following-sibling::td/b/text()
```

Comment: this works with me, thanks! and is it possible to ignore some inner tags like <font> etc, like to write a kind of universal xpath expression. The problem is that i need to scrap about 30 sites like that so that not to write separate xpath expression to each of them?

Comment: as said, either `/` with all tags or `//` that will skip tags in between, you can also use `*` for any tag, no other magic...